# Custom Action Menu for particular Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want my Custom Action Menu to be applied to particular list; currently its specified with the following XML and it gets applied to all the lists!

More specifically speaking; I even want this custom action to be applied to a particular view of the particular list...

```
<CustomAction
    Id="MyCustomActionId"
    Title="My Custom Action"
    Description="My Custom Action Description"
    RequireSiteAdministrator="FALSE"
    RegistrationType="List"
    GroupId="ActionsMenu"
    Sequence="1000"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu" >
    <UrlAction Url="{SiteUrl}/_layouts/MySharepointArtifacts/MyCustomAction.aspx?ListId={ListId}"/>
  </CustomAction>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I already have stsadm extension in place to fix the lookup fields. It would be fine to add another extension. Can I access the Custom Action being configured through Sharepoint Object Model?

Comment: I have also tried adding the link in the list' schema.xml (List / Views / ViewHeader) and its being accepted by the users. There I need to know the equivalent of UrlAction ~site moniker to give in <HTML />

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creeate a content type (based on the item you want to create the ECB menu on) and add the content type to your list. Create a customAction and register it to the content type. The ECB menu will only show on items of the given content type in lists where you added the content type.

Here is a Content type base on the build in document content type:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements Id="f55bc095-86f5-4c0a-961e-0e8f8e6c50ed" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ContentType ID="0x0101002936a05e70da4cf2a6846c669da7fdb6"
               Name="CTName"
               Group="CT group Name"
               Description="CT description"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>...
```

Create a custom action to the content type (ref. content type id):

```
    <CustomAction
        Id="MyCustomActionId"
        Title="My Custom Action"
        Description="My Custom Action Description"
        RequireSiteAdministrator="FALSE"
        RegistrationType="ContentType"
RegistrationId="0x0101002936a05e70da4cf2a6846c669da7fdb6"
        GroupId="ActionsMenu"
        Sequence="1000"
        Location="EditControlBlock" >
        <UrlAction Url="{SiteUrl}/_layouts/MySharepointArtifacts/MyCustomAction.aspx?ListId={ListId}"/>
      </CustomAction>
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but for me, this code only worked with "Location="EditControlBlock".

Comment: @lividsquirrel is correct -- locking a CustomAction down to a particular Content Type ID through the above method doesn't work when Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu" and GroupId="ActionsMenu", but it does work when Location="EditControlBlock" (again as @lividsquirrel states).

Comment: It's correct that you must use the Location="EditControlBlock" to make it work. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to target customActions to specific lists. One very tiny description I've found is here: http://www.dotnetprodigy.com/2009/01/how-to-create-custom-action-specific-to.html (and another here: http://mnish.blogspot.com/2009/04/create-custom-action-specific-to-list.html)